# How to separate error and success button from my js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After googling, i got some click effects on my buttons,

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kzr9ymx0/

Here one button is for success and another one is for error.

So i want to move this code to my web page form submission.

Now i have little bit confusion, which one is apply for error and which one is apply for success.

Here name of the class is same for both buttons, that's why i am struggling.

Here is classie.js code:

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Here name of the class is same for both buttons, that's why i am struggling."*. You can add different classes to buttons.

Comment: @dfsq: if i change means, it will trigger in my js right? thanks

Comment: i think, there is something have change in my js file @dfsq

Comment: Probably. You should also post you js code.

Comment: you can use :nth-of-type() selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-of-type() selector, 
Assume first button is for success and second button is for error, then use

code for success button click

```
$('button:nth-of-type(1)').on('click',function(){

});
```

code for error button click

```
$('button:nth-of-type(2)').on('click',function(){

});
```

Comment: Since I know nothing of your javascript code, preferably write bottom of the js file and check

Comment: Try with above fiddle. hope it helps

Comment: after opening jsFiddle link, click run once and check

Comment: I am using ur jsFiddle code, I am not getting any click effects on click of button.

Comment: Your question is you have confusion with which button to use for success and error. So I provided the jquery selector click for those 2 buttons and added alert for difference

Comment: yeah, you discontinued the chat?

Comment: typo mistake.. got solution?

Comment: I am not getting whats ur prob? you need seperate click function for both buttons right?

Comment: yes @gopinath: i need to use one button[success] for my some page,, and another one button[error] need to use in my some other page

Comment: What u wanna do onclick of success and error buttons?

Comment: I have already provided you two selectors to differentiate button click,